# Rewrite URL's parameters and remove query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to do a 301 re-direct and a re-write my URL parameters in one go. I have been following some answers around here, but can't get it to work. Here is what I tried. Comments indicate what I hope it does, not what it actually does.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect from "/country.php?country=FR&recipe=Croissant" to "/FR/Croissant"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^country\.php/?country=([A-Z]{2})&recipe=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/%1/$2 [NE,L,R=301]
# Redirect from "/country.php?country=FR" to "/FR"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^country\.php/?country=([A-Z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/%1 [NE,L,R=301]

# Internally map "/FR/Croissant" to "/country.php?country=FR&recipe=Croissant"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/([A-Z]{2})/(.+)/?$ country\.php/?country=$1&recipe=$2 [L]
# Internally map "/FR" to "/country.php?country=FR"
RewriteRule ^/([A-Z]{2})/?$ country\.php/?country=$1 [L]
```

But this does not work. Nothing happens when I try either of the examples:

`/country.php?country=FR&recipe=Croissant` stays `/country.php?country=FR&recipe=Croissant` and `/FR/Croissant` returns a 404.

I am running this on a subdirectory of a domain (localhost/food/, with localhost/food/index.php and localhost/food/country.php), but the htaccess file is placed in that directory `localhost/food/`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix regex pattern and some syntax issues:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /food/

# Redirect from "/country.php?country=FR&recipe=Croissant" to "/FR/Croissant"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /country\.php\?country=([A-Z]{2})&recipe=([^&\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [NE,L,R=301]

# Redirect from "/country.php?country=FR" to "/FR"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /country\.php\?country=([A-Z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [NE,L,R=301]

# ignore rules below for files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Internally map "/FR/Croissant" to "/country.php?country=FR&recipe=Croissant"
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/(.+?)/?$ country.php?country=$1&recipe=$2 [L,QSA]

# Internally map "/FR" to "/country.php?country=FR"
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/?$ country.php?country=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To fix issue with styles, images etc you need to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Or else, you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/food/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: I am running this on a subdirectory of a domain (localhost/food/, with localhost/food/index.php and localhost/food/country.php). I added `RewriteBase /food/`, and it's not working. The first part doesn't work at all, and the second only very partially. `/FR` correctly redirects, but when you add a slash, i.e. `/FR/` the styles are not loaded on the page, i.e. relative paths don't work any more.

Comment: That's true. I'm sorry. But the htaccess file is put IN that subdirectory only though, so I don't know if that's a problem.

Comment: Thanks, this works. If I'd use this on the base domain (e.g. localhost/), should I simply only remove the RewriteBase and <base>?

Comment: To use with root directory just use `RewriteBase /` and `<base href="/" />`